# windows: start bash.exe in new window with title

Tags: windows, bash, git-bash

How can I give a title to a window opened using `git bash -c "some command"` on windows? 
I've looked everywhere, honestly I absolutely can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

On my Git-bash, the title is update by prompt

```
$ echo "$PS1"
\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:${PWD//[^[:ascii:]]/?}\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\]\n$
```

Changing following variable

```
$ TITLEPREFIX="hello, world!"
```

Comment: hi, could you give an example of how to use your suggestion in the script that I posted? To be specific, the script I am launching with `git bash -c` is not my own and cannot itself be modified (I can add commands before and after though)